# Dynamic text in C#

Tags: c#, regex, string, replace

Given a function `object GetValue(string key)` as a data storage endpoint, I want to be able to do the following:

Text example: `Deals [damageMin]-[damageMax] damage to target`

Output example: `Deals 1-2 damage to target`.

What is a good way to find and replace all instances of `[varName]`?

I guess with Regex but not sure. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: see `string.Replace`. You should at least try **something** before asking here.

Comment: Maybe string interpolation can do the job : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/tokens/interpolated

Comment: How does the function from first line play into this?

Comment: Sorry but I want to capture all [varName] instances, as damageMin is only an example. The key can be any string

Comment: why do you replace data in the string in the first place instead of calculating your data **before** priniting?

Comment: @Vernou string interpolation is compile-time only, I need something the original text to be serializable

Comment: @HimBromBeere serialization

Comment: Do you need to denote the inserts with square brackets or is that flexible?

Comment: @JohnathanBarclay any special character would work fine

Comment: Use `String.Format` directly,so that both the format string and parameters are runtime depedant, instead of string interpolation that is a compile time only feature.

Comment: @Alejandro I need pre-formatted string to be serialized, so this unfortunately doesn't work

Comment: @Sindorej What does it means "serialized"?

Comment: Poor duplicate selection IMO. This question relates to _replacing_ an arbitrary number of substrings, not _removing_ a single substring.

Answer (score 0):

One option would be to store a dictionary of inserts:

```
var inserts = new Dictionary<string, string>
{
    ["{damageMin}"] = "1",
    ["{damageMax}"] = "2"
};
```

Then use Regex to replace them in the string:

```
string template = "Deals {damageMin}-{damageMax} damage to target";
string output = Regex.Replace(template,
    string.Join("|", inserts.Keys), match => inserts[match.Value]);
```

This works by creating a Regex like this: `{damageMin}|{damageMax}`, which matches all inserts and looks up their replacements in the dictionary.

You could then wrap this in a method:

```
string ApplyInserts(string template, IDictionary<string, string> inserts)
{
    return Regex.Replace(template,
        string.Join("|", inserts.Keys), match => inserts[match.Value]);
}
```

---

`{` and `}` are used to denote the inserts as they have no special meaning in Regex, unlike `[` and `]`, which would otherwise need to be escaped.

Comment: @Sinatr No, but they stated in the comments that any character could be used to denote the inserts.

Comment: Sorry, didn't read all comment.

Comment: Interesting, although in this case template should be pregenerated, it would be cool to be able to do something similar without a pregenerated list.